# How to replace a trapz function with a sum function?

Tags: matlab, function, syntax, sum, syntax-error

I have a working code and I'm trying to switch from using the `trapz` function to the `sum` function for part of it. I'm fairly certain that this will improve the accuracy of the codes output.

The original code is this:

```
W = -3:.1:3;
W_for_X = -30:30;
H = zeros(size(W));
H(23:37) = 4;
N = 4;
n = -30:30;
xn = zeros(size(n));
remB = rem(n,N)==0;
xn(remB) = cos(.1*pi*n(remB))-(4*sin(.2*pi*n(remB)));
w = 1;
for k = 1:length(W_for_X)   
    EXP = exp(-1i*w*W*W_for_X(k));
    Xw(k)=trapz(W,xn.*EXP);  
end
```

In the following attempts I did not change anything in the code except what I paste here. I am trying to switch function, but I am having trouble working out the details. I have tried to just directly substitute in the sum function and change out `W` for `k` but that didn't work.

```
for k = 1:length(W_for_X)
    EXP = exp(-1i*w*W*W_for_X(k));
    Xw(k)=sum(xn.*EXP,k);
end
```

This code yields this error: **In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.**

After taking a better look at the syntax for the `sum` function I tried to do it this way:

```
for k = 1:length(W_for_X)
    EXP = exp(-1i*w*W*W_for_X(k));
    Xw(k)=sum(xn.*EXP,L = 1..61);
end
```

The produced the following error: 
**Xw(k)=sum(xn.*EXP, L = 1..61);**

**Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.**

I then tried removing the loop to see if that would help things along:

```
k = 1:length(W_for_X);
    EXP = exp(-1i*w*W*W_for_X(k));
    Xw(k)=sum(xn.*EXP, L = 1..61);
```

**Error using  ***

**Inner matrix dimensions must agree.**

What am I doing wrong with my syntax, and how do I fix it?

**EDIT/ADD** - 1

A code that does the summation correctly is this (the rest of the code stays the same):

```
Xw = zeros(1,61);
for k = length(W);
    EXP = exp(-1i*w.*W(k).*W_for_X);
    Xw(k)=sum(xn.*EXP);
end
```

The only issue is that when I `disp (Xw)` only the last value in the vector is non zeros. Could someone explain why this is? I'm currently trying to figure out how to fill the whole matrix and not just the last value but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Are you looking at [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/sum.html)? That's the documentation for MuPAD's `sum` function – see the top of the page. Unless you're doing symbolic calculations, you don't want to use it. And you need to call it specially if you want use it within Matlab.

Comment: @horchler That is exactly what I was looking at. I didn't realize that it wasn't the same as `sum`. Though I've gotten away from trying to code it that way as of the last edit.

Comment: Maybe: `for k = 1:length(W)`?

Comment: @horchler that was correct.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: You are mixing loop-concepts with the vector-abilities of Matlab. Start removing that *k = ...* stuff:

```
EXP = exp(-1i*w*W*W_for_X);
```

Secondly, I don't know what

```
L = 1..61
```

is supposed to mean. I assume, this will cause another error, once you fix the inner dimension problem. This should work:

```
Xw=sum(xn.*EXP);
```

where Xw will contain the sum.

Then again, you previously stated an integral (based on the trapz-function) that considered the *W* as grid along which you integrate. Thus, I assume, what you are looking for is

```
Xw = W.*sum(xn.*EXP,1);
```

As I don't see any reason for such a complicate procedure, you can retrieve the overall sum right away by

```
Xw_sum = sum(W.*xn.*EXP);
```

Comment: The reason I used `L` was because [the sum function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/sum.html) seemed to suggest a two part expression within the `sum(function,i = a..b)` I have a feeling that that isn't correct. The error as a result of the `Xw` is snowballing, so the `Xw_sum` isn't working either.

Also after utilizing the reduced code `Xw=sum(xn.*EXP);` I ran into the following error:

Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: I don't know where you have the sum(function, i=a..b) from, but I don't see any of it at the official Matlab documentation at http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/sum.html. I assumed, that the inner matrix dimensions of W, xn, and EXP (they should!) are the same.. if this is not the case, check where the problem stems from using the command size(), e.g. size(W), size(xn), size(EXP) - does it yield the same output for all of them?